# Can you get extra lives (ships) in Galaga?

Tags: galaga

Is there a way to get extra lives/ships in Galaga?  I'm using this emulation: http://www.freegalaga.com/galaga.swf

Also I'd like to know it it's possible to get a triple-ship.  i.e. .|^|^|^|.  You can get the double ship by getting abducted by an alien then shooting down the alien, does the same apply to get triple?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the original, you earn lives by Hi-Score. So the same should apply for that.

Comment: Are we talking a personal HiScore or a system HiScore?

Comment: At 10,000 points and every 10 or 15 after that.

Answer (score 0):

We shouldn't assume any port or re-creation of Galaga is faithful to the original but it is interesting to see how the original game handled this, at least as a starting point.

### 1. Namco Galaga 1981 Coin-operated Arcade machine

Galaga was created by Namco but in the USA it was licenced by Miday, they manufactured the cabinets sold in the USA and produced a 
"Parts and Operating Manual" for Galaga:

[image: Galaga Manual Front Cover]

On Page 2-5 it shows the operator's switch-settable options for extra lives:

[image]

So depending on how the operator set-up their machine, you would get an extra ship at 20,000 points another at 60,000 points and at each multiple of 60,000 points.

However the operator could set the machine so that you never get a bonus ship.

---

### 2. Namco Arcade Game Series: Galaga - available on Steam for PC.

This is an officially licenced port of Namco's Galaga.

In this game, as of 2020, there is a game-menu you can reach by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, you can select `Settings` then `Game Settings`:

[image: Galaga game settings]

This offers exactly the same options as the original coin-operated arcade machine  but defaults to the second set of options for extra lives (maybe this was also the default out of the factory for the original machine)

---

### 3. Galaga ROMs in MAME 0.217

If you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> while running Galaga in MAME you get a menu

[image: Galaga MAME menu]

If you select `DIP switches` you get the same range of choices as in the original manual and in the Steam version from Namco.

[image: Galaga MAME dip-switches]

Again, there are the same range of options for extra lives and the default is the 20,000 / 70,000 / 70,000 option.

---